# need to find current textbox line in relationship to screen position

Tags: c#, textbox

I have created a texteditor along with a function window.

the functionwindow is a listbox that is populated with all of the functions located in the textbox.

when the user double clicks on an item in the listbox, the textbox will find the function that was clicked on. its just using a simple search to find the text. the issue is that if the text is at the bottom of the window, then you still need to scroll to display it properly. is there a way to ... If line 200 of a textbox was located at the bottom of the screen to make it show at the top??? does this make any sense to anybody

Comment: what platform? winforms? asp.net? silverlight? wpf? (etc.)

Comment: sorry, winforms 3.5 for now but i may go back as far as i can

Answer (score 1):

Is it the [ScrollToCaret](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.scrolltocaret.aspx) function you want?

Comment: I dotn think so. even with ScrollToCaret, it will display the text at the bottom of the control. Thats what im trying to figure out is if the text is at the bottom of the control, how to make it scroll so the text is at the top

Comment: I think you will have to work that out. Find out how many lines are in your text box and offset the caret by that amount?

Comment: is there a way to find out where the line is displayed on the screen as far as top/bottom etc?

Comment: heres a question. is there a way to show what lines are currently displayed? ie if lines 3-56 are displayed and i know that my current line is 53, i could move 53 to the top somehow